# how should I store articles and vocabulary

Tags: android, storage

I need an advice of some experienced coders, as I'm a newbie to android and such a complex application design.

I am designing a server-client application for my thesis where  **on the server** i have a database of articles and vocabulary and **on the device** is a reader of articles that user requests from the server according to vocabulary (- will be used for revision/ learning new words) he chooses.

I would like to know what would be a suitable way to store the articles (not more than 20) and vocabulary (200 words) on the device. So the question is: a database or files?  As a communication protocol I use REST, the articles are received in JSON format.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is using SQLite Database.

Here is a excellent tutorial on how to get started

[SQLite database with android](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)